# Roman to decimal conversion

Tags: c++, recursion, roman-numerals

What do you think about this code? Is it the best way? Any improvement?

Roman.h

```
#ifndef ROMAN_H
#define ROMAN_H

#include <string>

#include <map>

typedef unsigned long int UL_I;
typedef std::map< std::string, UL_I, std::less< std::string > > Map;

class Roman_Number
{
public:
  //Constructor
  Roman_Number( std::string );

  void Convert_to_decimal();

  UL_I get_Decimal() const;
  std::string get_Roman() const;

private:
  std::string s_roman_number;
  UL_I d_number;

  Map pairs;
  Map pairs_substracting;

  //Utilitaries functions
  void _validate_();
  void _initilize_pairs_()
  {
    pairs.insert( Map::value_type( "I", 1 ) );
    pairs_substracting.insert( Map::value_type ( "IV", 4 ) );
    pairs.insert( Map::value_type( "V", 5 ) );
    pairs_substracting.insert( Map::value_type( "IX", 9 ) );
    pairs.insert( Map::value_type( "X", 10 ) );
    pairs_substracting.insert( Map::value_type( "XL", 40 ) );
    pairs.insert( Map::value_type( "L", 50 ) );
    pairs_substracting.insert( Map::value_type( "XC", 90 ) );
    pairs.insert( Map::value_type( "C", 100 ) );
    pairs_substracting.insert( Map::value_type( "CD", 400 ) );
    pairs.insert( Map::value_type( "D", 500 ) );
    pairs_substracting.insert( Map::value_type( "CM", 900 ) );  
  }
  UL_I _recursive_convert( std::string );
};

#endif
```

Roman.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

#include "Roman.h"

void Roman_Number::_validate_()
{
  std::cout << "Validating" << std::endl;

}

Roman_Number::Roman_Number(std::string r_number )
{
  _initilize_pairs_();
  s_roman_number = r_number;
  d_number = 0;
}

void Roman_Number::Convert_to_decimal()
{
  std::string s_aux = s_roman_number;
  d_number = _recursive_convert( s_aux );
}

UL_I Roman_Number::_recursive_convert( std::string new_roman )
{
  if( new_roman == "" )
    return 0;
  if( pairs_substracting.find( new_roman.substr( 0 , 2 ) ) != pairs_substracting.end() )
     return pairs_substracting[new_roman.substr( 0, 2 )] + 
        _recursive_convert( new_roman.erase( 0, 2) );
  else
     return pairs[new_roman.substr( 0, 1 )] + _recursive_convert( new_roman.erase( 0, 1 ) );
}

UL_I Roman_Number::get_Decimal() const
{
  return d_number;
}

std::string Roman_Number::get_Roman() const
{
  return s_roman_number;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

#include "Roman.h"

int main() {
  Roman_Number R_N( "XIL" );
  R_N.Convert_to_decimal();
  std::cout << R_N.get_Decimal();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Programmers](http://Programmers.stackexchange.com) is a better site for review requests. Also there was a similar question on [codegolf.stackexchange.com](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/797/roman-numeral-converter-function)

Comment: I give it VIII out of X stars.

Comment: I'd recommend using http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ if you want generic comments on code you've written.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about this? http://codepad.org/mJ05BldC

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ) {
  const char* s = "MCDXLIV";
  int x = 0; // result

  int j,m=0; // max used digit
  const char* p=s, *q; while(*p) ++p;
  for( --p; p>=s; p-- ) for( q="IVXLCDM",j=0; *q; q++,j++ ) if( *p==*q )
    x += ((j>=m)?m=j,1:-1) * (1+j%4/2*9) * (1+j/4*99) * (1+j%2*4);

  printf( "s=%s x=%i\n", s, x );
}
```

Comment: I think my eyes just exploded.

Comment: Shelwien loves to confuse ppl

Answer (score 1):

Given

```
public static final String romanNums = "IVXLCDM";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = console.nextLine();

    int arabInt = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < romanNums.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < input.length(); j++) {
           if (input.substring(j, j + 1).equals(romanNums.substring(i, i + 1))) {
              arabInt += convertRomToNum(i);
              if (j > 0 && romanNums.indexOf(input.substring(j, j + 1)) > romanNums.indexOf(input.substring(j - 1, j))) {
                 arabInt -= 2 * convertRomToNum(romanNums.indexOf(input.substring(j - 1, j)));
              }
           }
    } 
  // AFTER OBSERVING PATTERN: 1, 5, 10, 50, 100, 500, 1000; AND ASSOCIATING INDEXES 
  // OF EACH ROMAN LETTER WITH CORRESPONDING NUMBER IN SEQUENCE ABOVE

public static int convertRomToNum(int i)  {    
    int numBehindLetter = (int) (Math.pow(2, Math.floor(i / 2)) * Math.pow(5, Math.ceil(i / 2.)));
    return numBehindLetter;
}
```

1 = 5^0 * 2^0; 5 = 5^1*2^0; 10 = 5^1*2^0; 50 = 5^2*2^1; 100 = 5^2*2^2; 500 = 5^3*2^2; 1000 = 5^3*2^3 and so on. This is why I have used 'floor' and 'ceil' functions.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere between convoluted and readable ...

```
int convRomanToInt(string roman) {

    char[] symbol = {  'M', 'D', 'C', 'L', 'X','V','I' };
    int[]  weight = { 1000, 500, 100,  50,  10, 5 , 1  };

    int res = 0, rom = 0, num = 0;

    while (rom < roman.Length){     
        if (roman[rom] == symbol[num]){
            res += weight[num];
            rom++;
        } else if (rom < roman.Length-1 && roman[rom+1] == symbol[num]){
            res -= weight[(num&~1)+2];
            rom++;
        } else {
            num++;
        }      
    }

    return res;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.